# Rails 2.3.14 No Route for .js.erb File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

In my layout footer I am including page specific JavaScript files like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}" if javascript_exists?("#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}") %>
```

The helper I am using is from another question on this site but modified to work with Rails 2:

**application_helper.rb**

```
def javascript_exists?(script)
  script = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/javascripts/#{script}.js"
  extensions = %w(.coffee .erb .coffee.erb) + [""]
  extensions.inject(false) do |truth, extension|
    truth || File.exists?("#{script}#{extension}")
  end
end
```

Then I also `init` the included file:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        <%= "#{params[:controller].titleize}#{params[:action].titleize}.init();" if javascript_exists?("#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}") %>
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine if my file is named `controller_action.js` but once renamed to `controller_action.js.erb` Rails generates an error because it can't find it.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/controller_action.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: ControllerAction is not defined
```

**Update**

If I use the `.rjs` extension then there are no errors generated but this seems to be because Rails doesn't think the file exists. (I updated the `javascript_exists?` with the `.rjs` extension.)

After some more debugging, the file **is** being located:

```
/path/public/javascripts/circuit_list.js true
```

but this returns `false` if `.rjs` is used.

The routing error when navigating to `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/controller_action.js` in the browser is:

```
No route matches "/javascripts/controller_action.js" with {:method=>:get}
```

Comment: I had used `rjs` in rails 2, long time.

Comment: @Nithin, strangely, If I use `.rjs` then there are no errors at all but that seems to be because Rails doesn't think the file exists.